# Using map and recursive functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

so I'm learning how to program in Haskell.

One thing I would like to see is adding 1 to each element of a list by using map and using recursion that doesn't use a list comprehension and without using map or any other higher-order library function.

I thought it'd be pretty cool to see both ways of implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you understand what `map` does then I think it won't be difficult to write what you intend to do. When you see the type of `map`

```
*Main> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So it takes a function and a list and returns another list after applying that function to each element of the list. So for your intended purpose to add one to each element you can choose the function to be `(+1)`. So

```
*Main> map (+1) [3,4,5,1,2]
[4,5,6,2,3]
```

Now defining your own function is easy if you understand the basic haskell. You can look at the source of `map` for help.

```
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

It gives you all the help you need to implement your recursive incrementing function like

```
add' [] = []
add' (x:xs) = (x+1) : add' xs
```

Now try this in ghci

```
*Main> add' [3,4,5,1,2]
[4,5,6,2,3]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Equational reasoning

Satvik explained the recursive version well, but there's something extremely interesting in the list comprehension version. Let's take a look.

```
add1 xs = [x + 1 | x <- xs]
```

List comprehensions have a syntax pretty similar to Python, but they're actually just syntax sugar for a normal language construct---`do` notation!

```
add1 xs = do x <- xs
             return (x + 1)
```

Since we're just operating on the list monad, we can desugar the `do` notation

```
add1 xs = xs >>= \x -> return (x + 1)
```

then apply some transformations

```
add1 xs = xs >>= return . (+1)
        = liftM (+1) xs
        = fmap  (+1) xs
        =  map  (+1) xs
```

And we're back to where we began.